# combination of array elements in scala

Tags: arrays, scala

I have a rdd of array[Int], like the following:

```
([0,1,7],[0,1],[0,1,3],...)
```

now I want to get the array combinations in each innerlist, like the following:

```
Array [[0,1,7], [0,7],[1,7],[7],[0,1],[1],[0,1,3],[0,3],[1,3],[3]]
```

How best way do that?

Answer (score 1):

You can do that using `combinations` from `Seq` trait and `flatMap` from Dataset API:

```
import spark.implicits._
val df = Seq(
  Array(0, 1, 7),
  Array(0, 1),
  Array(0, 1, 3)
).toDF("arr")
df.show()
val res = df.flatMap{
  row =>
    val rowSeq: Seq[Int] = row.getAs[Seq[Int]](0)
    (1 to rowSeq.length).flatMap(n => rowSeq.combinations(n))
}.collect().foldLeft(Set.empty[Array[Int]]){
 case (arrAcc, seqInt) => arrAcc + seqInt.toArray
}
println(res.map(a => a.mkString("[", ", ", "]")).mkString("[", ", ", "]"))
```

output will be:

```
df.show()
+---------+
|      arr|
+---------+
|[0, 1, 7]|
|   [0, 1]|
|[0, 1, 3]|
+---------+
res
[[1], [1, 7], [0], [0, 7], [0, 1], [3], [0, 1, 3], [0, 3], [7], [0, 1, 7], [1, 3]]
```

Comment: Thank you for your suppor. when I tried it, the error "value toDF is not a member of Seq[Array[Int] ". In addition, I would like the output of Array (0,1,3) as Array ((0,1,3), (0,3), (1,3), (3)) without (0), (1), (0,1)

Comment: @LamLe you should add `import spark.implicits._` before using `toDF`. If you want collect only distinct values, you can use `Set` instead of `Array`. I updated answer